# Toggle function not working properly in foreach

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript

Toggle function not working properly in foreach function

```
foreach($this->getCollection() as $res){

<input type="button" value=" <?php echo $helper->__('Order') ?></span> <strong>#<?php echo $res['magerealorderid']; ?>" id="hideshow1">
<div id="content1" style="display: none;">
 <?php echo Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getpronamebyorder($res['mageorderid']); ?> 
</div>


}
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#hideshow1').live('click', function(event) {        
         $('#content1').toggle('3000');

    });

 });

</script>
```

First loop working but next loop is not working

Comment: You are assigning static ID to HTML elements inside a loop. It will result in many HTML elements with the same ID on a page which is invalid and JS will not work properly. Work with classes and `this` operator instead. Moreover, it is not a Magento platform specific question, so you might get better answers on http://stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not specific to the Magneto platform. It is more of a general HTML - JS related problem.

Comment: how to overcome to assign dynamic id and use script

Comment: Even if you get to assign dynamic IDs, you'll still struggle with the JS part. Try with the class instead. Assign single class to all of them and then get the target element via `this`.

Comment: Can you plz give that script this

Comment: It might go something like this : `$('.hideshow1').live('click', function(event) {
 $(this).toggle('3000');
});`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not specific to the **Magento** platform. It is more of a general HTML - JS related problem.

Comment: Ok but its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add dynamic ids

```
foreach($this->getCollection() as $res){

<input type="button" class="buttontoggle" value=" <?php echo $helper->__('Order') ?></span> <strong>#<?php echo $res['magerealorderid']; ?>" id="hideshow<?php echo $res['magerealorderid']; ?>">
<div id="content<?php echo $res['magerealorderid']; ?>" style="display: none;">
 <?php echo Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getpronamebyorder($res['mageorderid']); ?> 
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#hideshow<?php echo $res['magerealorderid']; ?>').live('click', function(event) { 

         $('#hideshow<?php echo $res['magerealorderid']; ?>').toggleClass( "myClass yourClass" );       
         $('#content<?php echo $res['magerealorderid']; ?>').toggle('3000');

    });

 });

</script>
</div>


}
```

Comment: `$('#hideshow<?php echo $res['magerealorderid']; ?>').addClass( "myClass yourClass" );` you can add class like this

Comment: Is it right $('#hideshow<?php echo $res['magerealorderid']; ?>').addClass( "myClass yourClass" ).live('click', function(event)

Comment: updated the answer follow it..

Comment: it's a toggle so i need on click on class after that i remove that class

Comment: updated the answer follow add feedback..

Comment: No it's not remove

Comment: On click it's add after that it's not remove

Comment: did you add class on buttton ?

Comment: I add this class="buttontoggle" after click buttontoggle Show after hide also same buttontoggle Show

Comment: you are confusing me you want to add class on button on active and and remove class in acitve? that you want? or you want if the same button click then remove class..

Comment: Onclick it toggle so that time i need to add one class after that i click agin that time it hided so i want to remove that class for adding css so that i am asking

Comment: use toggle class it will do automatically